# pdfbox 2 - how to write from right to left

Tags: pdfbox, bidi

I'm using pdfbox version 2-RC3

Was able to use unicode. the probelm is that the text I'm getting on the pdf is from left to right.
I need to write Hebrew from right to left.
How do I do it?

```
package pdfProj.test;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font;

public class utftext {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);
        File tnrFontFile = new File("c://temp//font//times.ttf");
        PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, tnrFontFile);
        PDPageContentStream stream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        String text = "Hello how r u?  שלום מה שלןמך";
        stream.beginText();
        stream.setFont(font, 12);
        stream.moveTextPositionByAmount(50, 600);
        stream.drawString(text);
        stream.endText();
        stream.close();
        document.save("c://temp//pdf//type0_1.pdf");
        document.close();
    }
}
```

the output is:

[image]

Ended up with this:

```
    public static String getStrAccordingToLocal(String str)
{
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder(str);
    
    if (CommonUtil.notEmpty(str) && PdfUtil.isEnglishAsccii(str.charAt(0)))
    {
        return str;
    }
    value.reverse();
    
    return value.toString();
}
```

Comment: to make it simpler, can assume all the text in the pdf will be with same lanauge, at this case Hebrew.

Comment: I can think on writing reverse method this can solve the issue. wonder if there is something more formal as part of the PDFBOX.

Comment: I'm also stuck on this. Did you end up going with the backwards fix?

Comment: Yes, see sample added as part of the question.